# Occasional Missing Carriage Return on Output Window from Debug.Writeline

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Using debug.writeline, *sometimes* I end-up with four or five lines strung together in the Debug Output screen. It is like it decides not to output the \r\n for a few lines. Then, it starts doing it right again.

It is generated at the same place in the program every time it does happen and it is always a Debug.Writeline statement (not Debug.Write).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I'll do better than that..... I found the answer.

Bottom line: Don't have nulls in your string you want Debug.WriteLine to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Bottom line: Don't have nulls in your string you want Debug.WriteLine to display the entire line and append the CR on the end.